# Wanting to refactor these nested javascript loops of arrays and the conditional if statements

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have an outer and inner loop that I need to be able to display input text boxes on the outer loop, meanwhile I need to look at the inner loop to exclude value that are in that array.  I have tried many different ways and adjustments - this seems to be working  - but it looks frickin ugly doesn't it?  What can be done to improve readability?

```
var attName = 'IVS-REC-TYP','a', 'b', 'c', 'd';

var listTEDNoEdit = ['IVS-REC-TYP', 'IVS-TM-STAMP', 'IVS-ADJ-KEY', 'IVS-TCN-FILING-DT', 'IVS-TCN-FILING-ST-CTRY', 'IVS-TCN-SEQ', 'IVS-DT-PROCESSED', 'IVS-ADMIN-CLIN', 'IVS-NBR-LINES', 'IVS-LINE-NBR', 'IVS-DT-PROCESSED', 'IVS-DEERS-DDS', 'IVS-LINE-AMT-ALLOWED'];


// OUTER Loop is  attName
// INNER Loop is looking to exclude these values in this array called listTEDNoEdit 

for (i = 0; i < tagAttr.length; i++) {

  var attName = tagAttr[i].localName;

  for (index2 = 0; index2 < listTEDNoEdit.length; index2++) {

      if (attName === listTEDNoEdit[index2]) {
        tagAttrText += "<li>" + attName + " = " + attText + "</li>";
        break;
      } else {
          var tedEx = listTEDNoEdit.indexOf(attName);

          if (tedEx === -1) {
            tagAttrText += "<li>" + attName + " = <input type='text' value='" + attText + "'/></li>";
            break;
          } else {
            tagAttrText += "<li>" + attName + " = " + attText + "</li>";
            break;
          }
          break;
      }
  } 

}
```

Comment: If you `break` in every branch of the `if`, you always exit the loop on its first iteration, so why do you need the loop in the first place?

Comment: because if outer loop is = 'first' and the inner loop was = 'not_first' then I ended up with the else statement then still writing out something else in the array.   seems like it is working.... but my real intention with the break was to just not have it enter the else statement.   I did beef up the else statement with searching indexOf ... so I have not properly tested the need of the break ..   thoughts?